# Create a keyboard shortcut that maps to the down/up arrows on the keyboard in Fedora

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, fedora

I would like to map Alt+N and Alt+P to the down arrow and up arrow, respectively. I want to do this because various popup dialogs in eclipse require the user to type the arrow keys and no shortcuts defined in eclipse (e.g., line-down) are effective in these dialogs.

what's the easiest way to accomplish this in eclipse? It should be ok for the setting to be global rather than just for eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using KDE, you can easily do it using the extremely flexible Shortcuts module (one of the many reasons I love KDE). Try this:

1. In Configure Desktop, type Custom Shorcuts into the search box and open the respective dialog (that is Common Appearance and Behavior > Shortcuts and Gestures > Custom Shortcuts, in the old tree-style mode)
2. Select Edit > New > Global Shorcut > Send Keyboard Input
3. Now, on the Trigger tab, enter your desired shortcut key combination (I tried it with Alt+N)
4. On the Action tab, type 'Down' into the box (without the quotes)
5. Click Apply

Alt+N should now be equal to pressing the down key. (It works analogously with the keyword 'Up')

Edit:
The Shortcuts module allows you to limit your configuration to Eclipse (or any other program) too, should you desire so.